# What is the difference between two declarations, : and = in angular 2?

Tags: typescript

**angular code**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    hero = 'Ram'; // line 1
    hero: 'Ram'; // line 2
}
```

I don't really understand the difference between line1 and line2. Please help me

Comment: Why is this tagged angular??

Answer (score 2):

Operator `=` is used to assign value, while operator `:` is used to assign type. Let's say you have this code:

```
hero = 'Ram';
hero1: 'Ram';
```

If you try to do `console.log(hero)`, it will print `Ram` because you are assigning value `Ram` to variable `hero`, while `console.log(hero1)` will probably print `undefined` because you assigned type `Ram` to variable `hero1`, but you didn't assign any value to it.

Comment: No no. I got the answer. actually **:** is used for type. we can assign value with type by using : colon. example:
`hero = 'Ram';
hero1 : number = 100;`

Answer (score 2):

It's really easy actually, line 1 means that you set the value "Ram" to hero so I guess it's the Hero name ? 
And basically, you use ':' to set a specific variable type.

For example, If I type : let name: boolean = false; my variable name will be considered as a boolean.
By default, if you don't specify the type with :type, it will be :any , like any JavaScript variable.

Also, as Amit said, it's more related to a TypeScript question than Angular2.

Comment: Please do not forget to validate answers if possible. Thx.